# Common Lisp THE gives no compiler warnings

Tags: common-lisp, compiler-warnings

From the examples given for the `THE` function (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_the.htm) when i change the following form

```
(the (values integer float) (truncate 3.2 2))
```

to

```
(the (values integer integer) (truncate 3.2 2))
```

I still don't get any compiler warnings, whereas `(the integer 1.2)` gives

> ;Compiler warnings :
>   ;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 0: Type declarations violated in (THE INTEGER 1.2)

Can some one explain why the above doesn't produce warnings? I test these on CCL.

Comment: i guess you would have to set the safety optimization value: `(declaim (optimize (safety 3)))`

Comment: I tested with SBCL and there is a warning

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood what `the` does.  The specification tells you in so many words:

> `the` specifies that the values returned by form are of the types specified by value-type. *The consequences are undefined if any result is not of the declared type.*

(My emphasis.)

In other words, what `the` does is to allow you to say to the compiler 'I undertake that these things have these types and you may compile appropriate code for that, with no checks needed; if that's not true then I fully accept that you may need to set my hair on fire and gouge out my one remaining eye'.

Now, famously, CMUCL and its derivatives such as SBCL take a rather different approach to type checking.  From the [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Declarations-as-Assertions):

> The SBCL compiler treats type declarations differently from most other Lisp compilers. Under default compilation policy the compiler doesn’t blindly believe type declarations, but considers them assertions about the program that should be checked: all type declarations that have not been proven to always hold are asserted at runtime.

Thus the system treats `the` as an assertion about types which, if it is not already known to be true, must be checked.  This is, I think, conformant, since 'unspecified consequences' can obviously include 'raising an exception in a nice way' (personally I prefer eye-gouging compilers but that's just me).

But if you want to write portable code, you should not assume that `the` does this.  Rather you need either to accept the risks that it does not, or use some form like `check-type` or `assert` with a type check as the thing you are asserting.

Comment: Read also the next paragraph in CLHS: It is permissible for form to yield a different number of values than are specified by value-type, **provided** that the values for which types are declared are indeed of those types.

Comment: @Student: yes, but this is not relevant here: the type of `(truncate 3.2 2)` is simply not `(values integer integer)`, it is some subtype of `(values integer float)`.  Your example would matter if you had said, for instance, `(the integer (truncate 3.2 2))` or `(the float (truncate 3.2 2))`, but you did not.  And in all cases the system is *allowed but not required* to tell you about violations.